# React using audio element and ensure duration shows

Tags: reactjs, html5-audio

In have this audio tag defined like this:

```
<audio controls={true} src={src} preload='metadata' />
```

Where src is some url to an audio link.

Before playing the audio, the player looks like this:

[image]

It does not show the duration.
Only after playing it will show the duration like this:

[image]

Is there a way to show the duration at the start before playing? Or am I using this incorrectly?

Here is an example:

```html
<audio src='https://filebin.net/266mdduooymtmdhz/M2789gDcadGu6vLYVdZa.webm' controls preload='metadata' />
```

Comment: Works OK for me using, say, `<audio src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8e/Drums.ogg" controls preload="metadata">` on FF 119. Can you provide a [mcve]? What browser(s) are you using? Thanks.

Comment: [`preload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#preload) is a hint, so the browser doesn't have to respect it. I assume you're on Chrome based on the styling of the audio player but it's good to [edit] that into the question for posterity, along with a version number.

Comment: I have added an example: `<audio src='https://filebin.net/266mdduooymtmdhz/M2789gDcadGu6vLYVdZa.webm' controls preload='metadata' />`

Comment: That preloaded for me as well, so I guess it's a browser-specific thing.

Comment: really? you see the total time before playing it?

Comment: On FF 119 I do, Chromium 119 I don't. So it's a browser-dependent hint you can't rely on.

Answer (score 1):

From the MDN docs for audio's [`preload` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#preload):

> The default value is different for each browser. The spec advises it to be set to `metadata`.
>
> Note:
>
> The `autoplay` attribute has precedence over `preload`. If `autoplay` is specified, the browser would obviously need to start downloading the audio for playback.
>
> The browser is not forced by the specification to follow the value of this attribute; it is a mere hint.

You can't rely on this attribute being respected by the browser. For me, FF 119 shows the preloaded time without pressing play, but on Chromium 119, it doesn't.